# Entity framework: Foreign entity without requiring foreign entity to actually exist entity to exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an audit-tracking like system, that contains the following two entities:
The `JobCreate` entity:

```
public class JobCreate
{
    [Key] public string JobId { get; set; }

    public List<AffectedEntity> AffectedEntities { get; set; }
}
```

And the `AffectedEntity` entity:

```
public abstract class AffectedEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string JobId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [CanBeNull] public JobCreate Job { get; set; }
}
```

So far this is just a normal foreign key relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobCreate>()
    .HasMany(j => j.AffectedEntities)
    .WithOne(a => a.Job)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.JobId)
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Entity Framework generates a foreign key for this relationship. My problem with this is that this audit system is event driven, which means it receives the events that creates the `AffectedEntity` and the event that creates the `JobCreate` entries out of order. In other words, the `JobCreate` entity might not yet exist when the `AffectedEntity` is created. However as far as the domain goes, this is actually fine. So how do I model that in Entity Framework? I want to be able to "navigate" along that connection from `JobCreate` to `AffectedEntity`, however the other direction is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the JobCreate entity might not yet exist when the AffectedEntity is created. However as far as the domain goes, this is actually fine. So how do I model that in Entity Framework?

Just have the relationship in the EF model, but omit it or set the FK to not be enforced in the back-end.  EG in SQL Server you would set the Foreign Key Constraint to NOCHECK.

Just beware that EF may assume that the FK is enforced when it creates queries.  EG if you query `db.AffectedEntities.Inclue("JobCreate")` it may use an INNER JOIN and not return any AffectedEntities without a JobCreate.

And if you need to deal with AffectedEntities with a null JobID, you'd have to change the data type to `int?`.

Comment: Is there any way to do that in EF, without actually executing raw sql during a migration? And especially in a way that won't get overwritten on the next migration?

Comment: If you want the database to differ from the default EF-generated model, you'll have to make the change somewhere.  But you can integrate it into your migrations easilly, eg   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations